# laravel layout templat lost in subfolder url blade

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

My template layout blade doesn't render when the url is a subfolder.

I made a test example to check:

URL/tests is okay

but

URL/tests/1/edit loses the outer layout template and only renders the content.

Testcontroller:

```
class TestController extends AdminController {

 protected $layout = 'layouts.admin';

public function index()
{
    // load the view
    $this->layout->content=View::make('tests.index');

}
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $course=Course::find($id);

    return View::make('tests.edit')->with(array('course'=>$course));
}
```

}

layout admin.blade.php

```
<html><body>
{{ $content }}
</body>
</html>
```

tests/index.blade.php

```
hello
```

/tests renders source full layout html code and works fine on proper site examples

tests/edit.blade.php

```
edit
```

/tests/1/edit  renders with NO layout HTML

There are various ways of using blade but I thought the easiest was with protected layout but there seem to be issues?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit method instead of

```
return View::make('tests.edit')->with(array('course'=>$course));
```

use:

```
$this->layout->content= View::make('tests.edit')->with(array('course'=>$course));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AdminController` which is the base controller of your `TestController`, add the layout setings, put this code in your `AdminController`

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

Now you use any view with layout using something like this:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('tests.edit')->with(array('course'=>$course));
```

Here, `tests.edit` means that `edit.blade.php` (also could `edit.php` if not blade) file is in `app/views/tests/` directory.

In your `index` method you have used:

```
$this->layout->content=View::make('tests.index');
```

So the `layout` showed up because you set data to layout but in other example you didn't set data to `layout` so layout is not rendered, it's returning only the view as given below:

```
return View::make('tests.edit')->with(array('course'=>$course));
```

So, setup the layout in the base controller class so in your every controller you don't have to setup the layout, but always set data to the `content` variable of layout using this:

```
$this->layout->content = 'your data';
```